# fluidsynth in a cloud VM

Tags: sound, music, cloud, midi

What I want - to convert midi files into audio files with a soundfont on the cloud.

I can do that on my dual-booted Linux laptop, my MacBook, but I want to do it on the cloud, specifically GCP.

This alone does not work:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install fluidsynth
```

Running `fluidsynth` will give errors like

```
fluidsynth: error: Failed to connect to Jack server.
Failed to create the audio driver
```

I tried to apt-get install missing packages alike jackd2 and it just gives another set of errors.

Have anyone tried to synthesize music on the cloud before? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Whoospie we can actually ignore the error when you run only `fluidsynth` 
This works:  `fluidsynth -F ./test.wav GeneralUser\ GS\ v1.471.sf2 test.mid`

Comment: If you have an answer, please write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can actually ignore the error when you run only `fluidsynth`

This works: `fluidsynth -F ./test.wav GeneralUserGSv1.471.sf2 test.mid`

I still encounter this error message: `fluidsynth: warning: Failed to pin the sample data to RAM; swapping is possible.`

Specific instructions for my use case is in my [repo](https://github.com/tonghuikang/synthesize-test/).